# ¿Cómo puedo saber que se ha enviado el email?

Tags: java, android

Utilizo este botón para abrir un cliente de email y enviar el email:

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        etMensaje = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.GmailMensaje);
        String subject = "Hola";
        String message = etMensaje.getText().toString();

        Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"ejemplo@gmail.com"});
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

        email.setType("message/rfc822");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Selecione un cliente de correo"));
    }
});
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando haya enviado el email (automáticamente vuelve a mi aplicación) se ejecute un método, pero si no se ha enviado el email (haciendo clic atrás o algo similar), se ejecute otro método.

¿Es esto posible? Gracias!

**EDITO1**:

Teniendo en cuenta la respuesta de @Jorgesys , ¿es posible enviar un `TOAST` al volver de ese *Intent*?

Comment: Si no quieres usar intents para enviar el email y poder controlar todo http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_(no_Intents)_in_Android

Comment: He creado otra pregunta con ese tema, porque estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de enviar el email, si puedes mirarla te lo agradecería mucho: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/71591/por-qu%C3%A9-no-se-env%C3%ADa-mi-email-javamail @Webserveis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿Cómo puedo saber que se ha enviado el email?

En este caso no es posible ya que el Intent abre las aplicaciones que pueden enviar los email y son aplicaciones que son externas a tu aplicación android.

```
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Selecione un cliente de correo"));
```

En este caso lo único que puedes validar es si se inició correctamente la ventana para seleccionar el cliente con el cual enviarías el e-mail:

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        try{

        etMensaje = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.GmailMensaje);
        String subject = "Hola";
        String message = etMensaje.getText().toString();

        Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"ejemplo@gmail.com"});
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

        email.setType("message/rfc822");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Selecione un cliente de correo"));


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ocurrio un error al enviar al tratar de crear el e-mail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }
});
```

El mensaje de error al enviar lo determinaría la aplicación que realiza el envio.